# Как обесцветить изображение ImageIcon на Java?

Tags: java, изображения, icon

Как обесцветить изображение `ImageIcon`?
Надеюсь что существуют стандартные методы.

Comment: Есть стандартный метод `GrayFilter.createDisabledImage(Image i)`. Он имитирует тип disabled кнопки. [Офф. документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GrayFilter.html#createDisabledImage(java.awt.Image))

Comment: Интересно, но странно он делает изображения, не очень похоже что их обесцветили, какбуд-то они посерели

Comment: Да, это не стандартный grayscale. Его используют для того, чтобы получить disabled кнопку. А вам для чего?

Comment: Для обесцвечивания изображения) Дается картинка любая.

Comment: Я с изображениями в Java не работал, но алгоритм примерно такой - берешь цвет точки в RGB и усредняешь его. Т.е. был например оранжевый 255, 102, 0. Соответственно считаем c = (255 + 102 + 0) /3 = 119. Потом устанавливаем у этой точки новый цвет 119, 119, 119.

Comment: Да я так и думал делать но не знаю как.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать `ColorConvertOp`. Он попиксельно заменяет исходную картинку.

```
public BufferedImage getGreyScaled(BufferedImage src) {
    ColorConvertOp colorOp = new ColorConvertOp(
            ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
    return colorOp.filter(src, null);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Официальная документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html)

Чтобы из `BufferedImage` получить `ImageIcon` воспользуйтесь соответствующим конструктором `ImageIcon(Image image)`

Comment: Кластно) работает